# RegEx: Quote string after 'cite: '

Tags: php, regex

How can I put the text after a defined string (i.e. `cite:`) into quotes (if it isn't already quoted)? Optional there can be multiple spaces at the beginning of the line.

```
cite: Lorem ipsum
    cite: Lorem ipsum
cite: "Already quoted"
```

Should become

```
cite: "Lorem ipsum"
    cite: "Lorem ipsum"
cite: "Already quoted"
```

My attempt:

```
preg_replace("/[\s\t]cite:[\s\t]/","",$line);
```

But I don't get it correctly. These are my problems with that:

- Spaces at the beginning are optional and can be multiple
- I'm searching for `cite:` (with space) and I want to get the rest of the line
- Put the rest of the line in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or use this pattern

```
cite:\s*\K([^"]+?)$
```

and replace with `"$1"`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/225)

```
cite:           # "cite:"
\s              # <whitespace character>
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
\K              # <Reset start of match>
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^"]          # Character not in [^"]
  +?            # (one or more)(lazy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
$               # End of string/line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^(\s*cite: )([\w\s]+)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG6zC1/1)**

And use the replacement string:

```
$1"$2"
```

Look at the `Substitution` section below:

[image]

The php code would be:

```
$re = "/^(\\s*cite: )([\\w\\s]+)$/m"; 
$str = "cite: Lorem ipsum\n    cite: Lorem ipsum\ncite: \"Already quoted\""; 
$subst = "$1\"$2\""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: This works fine for the examples given. But only if the part after "cite: " is only letters/number/spaces. In my test I did real quick I used `(\w.*)` as the last part which only requires the first character be a word character. Otherwise exactly the same.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yes, you are right but I've based on OP sample data. If he adds more sample we can help him more accurately

Comment: Oh, and php also uses `$1`/`$2` for replacement groups.